# Remove AWS VPC Instance and its RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vps, rds

I want to remove VPS Instance in AWS and it's RDS.How to remove the both services in my account.

Comment: Is it a VPS Instance AWS LightSail or EC2?

Comment: it's a EC2 Default VPC

Comment: You want to delete the VPC or EC2 instance or RDS?

Comment: I want to delete VPC.The VPC having one RDS i want to delete both of this. But i am not able to see VPC related database in RDS.when i am trying to access RDS it only show Public database only.

Comment: Although database is public its placed inside a vpc in a public subnet. You need to delete the RDS instance.

Comment: Your comments (and the tags you added to this question) make me think you are confused about what an AWS VPC is (a private network). I think you are actually asking about deleting an EC2 (virtual server) instance and an RDS (managed database server) instance, not an entire VPC network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing because the title mentions **VPS**, while your question mentions **VPC** and **RDS**. So, here's some definitions:

- An **Amazon EC2 instance** is a virtual machine that runs in the AWS cloud. Some people might refer to a virtual machine as a **Virtual Private Server (VPS)**, but within AWS the term *VPS* is only really used with a virtual machine provisioned via **Amazon Lightsail**.
- An **Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)** is a virtual network in which resources (eg Amazon EC2 instances can be created). There is a **Default VPC** provided in an AWS account that should not (in general) be deleted.
- **Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS)** provides fully-managed database instances for SQL databases such as SQL Server, My SQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL.

If you wish to remove an Amazon RDS instance, go to the RDS management console, select the instance, then in the Instance Actions menu select **Delete**.

See: [Deleting a DB Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_DeleteInstance.html)

If you wish to remove an Amazon EC2 instance, go to the EC2 management console, select the instance, then go to the Actions menu and select Instance State -> Terminate.

See: [Terminate Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html)

I do not recommend that you delete your VPC unless you created it yourself.